# What benefits we have in reduction in clock cycles

Tags: power, low-power

If I implement a function with multiple algorithms but all providing same functionality and measure total number of clock cycles required to execute the program on a MCU platform, what benefits will reduction in clock cycle count will have?

For example algo A for function my_function() requires 1000 CC and Algo B for the same function requires 500 CC. After the execution my system goes to low power mode.

One obvious benefit is that because I have reduced the execution time by 50%, my system will enter low power mode quickly thus improving. However I want to ask that whether reduction in clock cycles itself will save power of transistor switching etc? and can I safely say that it is also reduced by 50%? it not then please explain this as I cannot grasp this idea. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first approximation, yes, reducing the run time between power-down periods from 1000 cycles to 500 cycles will cut the overall power drawn by half.

Upon closer look, there are various reasons the power reduction might not be exactly half, but the power will still be reduced significantly.  For example, the CPU probably doesn't draw the same average current for every instruction, the sleep power isn't completely zero, etc.

When writing microcontroller code for battery-operated devices, it is often useful to optimize for the least instruction cycles, for the reason you state.  This may mean using more program memory and the like.  Remember that memory usage only matters if you run out.  Techniques like unrolling often-used critical loops, and carefully hand-crafting critical routines in assembler can all make a difference.  However, your overall firmware architecture will probably make the biggest difference.  This includes decisions like what to do in interrupts routines, whether to use a main event loop architecture as apposed to a cooperative task scheduler, etc.

Comment: Assuming the average power of each clock cycle is equal, and the clock cycles are reduced by 50% between two low power modes? then my overall power consumption will exactly be reduced by 50%? or slightly more or less? ALso assuming that low power current for both algo implementation is equal.

Comment: @Hassan: In that case the overall power will be reduced by not quite 50%.  That is because there is still some finite power used during the sleep interval.  This may actually matter if the sleep interval is long compared to the full exuecution interval.  For example, consider 1 ms full execution every 10 seconds at 10 mA and 1 uA the rest of the time.  The run energy and the sleep energy are the same, and half the run time will only reduce the overall power by 25%.